# how can i get back to the original creation settings?

Tags: objects

[image]

Hi. I'm new to blender. If i do this helix ( or any other object-shape ) like in picture { 1 } and i move it or translate it like in picture { 2 } , how can i go back to this kind of settings for adjusting the helix in the work flow? Work flow description will help me.

Thank you.[image]

Comment: If I understand you right, the answer is you can't. Once you create an object you get a menu on the bottom left to change the parameters. Once you move the object or change it in any way outside of the menu you cannot get it back. You have to start over.

Comment: There may be some exceptions from the rule like Archimesh addon which allows to edit objects created with it but it doesn't include other objects